# Sbt imports always fails in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Everytime I try to create a scala sbt project, or import one, I get the following message:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/nke09/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/nke09/quiz-management-service/crud/project
/Users/nke09/quiz-management-service/crud/build.sbt:1: error: not found: value JavaAppPackaging
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
^
[error] Type error in expression
Invalid response.
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Do you have `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2")` in your `project/plugins.sbt`?

Comment: I don't have a plugins.sbt file?

Comment: Then you should create it and add the plugin

Comment: When I do that though it fails to get the plugins as well!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and the solution from @Luca T. worked for me:
add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2")` in my `project/plugins.sbt` file. As the file didn't exist, I created it under the `project` folder, next to the `build.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem. I thought that the reason was the conflict with your current sbt environment. My solution was deleting .sbt directory from /home/your user/